# Have one Rest repository json with everything and one with fields excluded

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have two entities: Book and Category and a repository for both. In the controller, I have set up the methods correctly as such:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@CrossOrigin
public @ResponseBody List<Book> bookListRest() {    
    return (List<Book>) bookRepository.findAll();
}
```

This obviously shows all books and every field in the entity that isn't @JsonIgnore'd. The problem is, I need to have:

- One page with Book data (book name, author name, isbn..) without category
- One page with Category data (Category name) without books
- One page with Everything (book data along with categories where they belong in)

How can one accomplish this? 
I somehow need to in a way ignore @jsonignore on some occasions. Should I make a new entity that extends say, Question and also make a repository for that? Surely that can't be the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As khalid Ahmed Said you can use costum dtos or you can add Filters to ignore specific fields in Jackson. First, we need to define the filter on the java object:

```
@JsonFilter("myFilterBook")
public class Book{
    ...
}

@JsonFilter("myFilterCategory")
public class Category{
    ...
}
```

Before you return your ResponseBody you try to use ObjectMapper (Jackson):

The case of one page with Book data (book name, author name, isbn..) without category:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter theFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
        .serializeAllExcept("category");
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
        .addFilter("myFilterBook", theFilter);
    String dtoAsString = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(book);
```

You can do the same think by putting what you want o ignore for the other example.

And for more details to ignore field during marshalling with jackson you can check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)

Comment: This was actually the solution that I used. Problem was, my rest api end points didn't work cause they were lacking filters (And adding them was a PITA). So I decided to use JSONViews
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Answer (score 1):

What about using `DTOs` `data transfer objects`

you can create multiple `DTOs` to use them in the response of your `API`

`DTO` is a `pojo` `class` that customize the returning data from your `entity`

```
 public class BookWithoutCategoryDTO {
   private String name;
   private String authorName;
   .....
   /// and make setters and getters for them


 }
```

---

```
 public class BookWithCategoryDTO {
   private String name;
   private String authorName;
   private String category;
   .....
   /// and make setters and getters for them


 }
```

and create your custom mapper to convert from `Book` to `BookDTO`